# Calculating standard error in linear regression

Tags: regression, standard-error, scipy

I have seen in a couple of places that the following expression gives the standard error in linear regression:

$$se = \sqrt{\frac{1-r^2}{N-2}}$$

where $r$ is the correlation coefficient. I was calculating this quantity by hand, and by `scipy`'s `linregress`, and I saw the two numbers differed. I checked the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.17.0/scipy/stats/_stats_mstats_common.py#L11-L102), and I found that the expression `linregress` uses for the standard error is the following:

$$se =\sqrt{\frac{1-r^2}{N-2}\frac{\sum (y_i-\bar{y})^2}{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2}}$$

What is the difference between these two expressions? What do they correspond to? How should I interpret them?

**Edit:** I forgot to specifiy that the data I'm concerned with is **bivariate**. I.e., I'm fitting a line on ${(x_i,y_i)}$.

**Edit 2:** I want to calculate the standard error on the correlation coefficient, $r$.

Comment: Welcome to our site! You probably should specify the context you mean - are you specifically interested in [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) ("y on x", the bivariate case) rather than multiple regression?

Comment: @Silverfish Thank you :) I meant bivariate, and I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: The formula for s.e. in linear regression ?  ? There is a formula for s.e. of correlation coefficient  which is s.e. of r = (1- r square)/sqr of (n-2).

Comment: 1. What specifically are you computing the standard error *of*? 2. When you say "bivariate" you mean that the y-variable is a vectore has two components? Or do you mean you have one-DV and one IV (i.e. one y and one x)?

Comment: the second equation is the standard error of b, not r, i believe

Comment: It would be helpful to see the "couple of places" that the expressions appeared so we can take a look.  Can you give us a reference?

Comment: that is to say, the first equation is the se for r, the second the se for b

Comment: @StatsStudent For instance: https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m113/coefficient_determination.html